# HashMap in a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, linkedhashmap

**Updated:-**

Problem Statement is-

I need to store these things-

```
For ID corresponding to 1, I need to Store these things

 - Key CGUID(String CGUID) and its Value, Key SGUID(String SGUID) and its Value, Key PGUID(String PGUID) and its Value, Key UID(String UID) and its Value, Key ALOC(String ALOC) and its Value

For ID corresponding to 2, I need to Store these things

- Key CGUID(String CGUID) and its Value, Key SGUID(String SGUID) and its Value, Key PGUID(String PGUID) and its Value, Key UID(String UID) and its Value, Key ALOC(String ALOC) and its Value

For ID corresponding to 3, I need to Store these things

- Key CGUID(String CGUID) and its Value, Key SGUID(String SGUID) and its Value, Key PGUID(String PGUID) and its Value, Key UID(String UID) and its Value, Key ALOC(String ALOC) and its Value
```

So for this problem I was thinking to make data structure like this-

```
public static LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> GUID_VALUES = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();

public static LinkedHashMap<Integer, LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>> GUID_ID_MAPPING = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>>();
```

Is there any better way to do than this?

Comment: Generics are for types, not values.

Comment: Sounds like a tree that supports path-based queries, a la XPath.

Comment: are CGUID key and value related from ID 1 and ID 2, in other words, it will be the same map or structure (this also applies on the others key/value pairs)?

Comment: By CGUID Key I mean String CGUID, I updated the question with more informaton.

Comment: Read the comment again, I've edit it.

Comment: Yes they are related to corresponding to ID's. As value can be different for each ID 1 and ID 2

Comment: Then it looks like you need a map of maps like @DaveNewton and me have posted. Also, if you're going to use it in a web application, I'll suggest you to avoid `static` variables and use a cache mechanism like [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, you could achieve that by using:

```
public class Data {
    public static LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> GUID_VALUES = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
    public static LinkedHashMap<Integer, Map<String, Integer>> GUID_ID_MAPPING = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Map<String, Integer>>();

    static {
        Integer someNumber = 0; //or another value, its for initialize the key
        GUID_ID_MAPPING.put(someNumber,GUID_VALUES);
    }
}
```

Still, I don't understand why you really need this. I'll suggest you to post your functional requirement and try to choose a better design to solve the problem.

Comment: I use maps of maps fairly often (although usually abstracted), it's a pretty typical structure, isn't it?

Comment: @DaveNewton yes, I'm just trying to check if the problem is bigger than this and it could have a better design solution :)

Comment: @Luggi, I just updated my question, Let me know if it stills confusing.

Comment: I understand :) It's hard to tell from the question what the actual requirements are :/

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what you're ultimately trying to store.

If you just want a map of maps:

```
LinkedHashMap<Integer, LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>>
```

But what's all that "etc etc etc" at the end? Are there multiple "children" IDs per parent ID? If so then you probably want some sort of tree (which could be implemented by maps, but an abstraction over that would seem reasonable.)

Comment: `LinkedHashMap<Integer, Map<String, Integer>>` on the left hand side

Comment: @assylias More likely on the right-hand side as a ctor, on the left-hand side you'd probably want to abstract the map implementation.

Comment: Actually `Map<Integer, Map<String, Integer>>` on lhs, and what I said on rhs, right? ;-)

Comment: @assylias Nope, on the left I'd almost always use `Map<Integer...etc>>` unless I specifically needed to communicate it preserved insertion order.

Comment: I just updated my question, Let me know if it stills confusing.

Comment: @Nevzz03 You added a single line for "id=3" as far as I can tell--that's not additional information. You also edited *out* what some of the answers were for, making things *more* confusing.

Comment: @Nevzz03 Not really--you added some carriage returns; also not additional information. AFAICT a map of maps is fine, though.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a multi key map, as the one available in Apache Commons Collections:

http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/map/MultiKeyMap.html

Comment: Hmm, not sure--not clear from the question, but it looks more like a single key, with nested maps--more like a tree.